# Are reagent-forms meant to be using with re-frame?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame, reagent-forms

I'm building an application with re-frame and I'm wondering if reagent-form are meant to be used with re-frame or not, as reagent-form brings in its own way of handling state which is different than re-frame.

Answer (score 8):

After experimenting a bit, I'd say it can be used, by completely ignoring the ratom that reagent-forms use for state and just using the callback, as in:

```
[bind-fields [form-template ...] default-values
               (fn [_ _ doc]
                 (re-frame.core/dispatch [:update-data doc]))]
```

but to me, it didn't feel right, ignoring that ratom with state. That's why I created a new library called [Free-form for creating forms with Reagent and optionally, with Re-frame](https://carouselapps.com/free-form/).

Free-form doesn't store state, it just has a similar callback mechanism and it comes with a layer that makes it plugging it into Re-frame straightforward (but optional). On top of that, it makes no assumptions about the shape of your form, you are in total control of your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but I think you shouldn't.

One thing you could do is just require twitter bootstrap and do some glueing to use everything in the re-frame way.